# Number of page in pdf too high in Quarto

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm trying to create a pdf report, using Quarto, in R. However, differently from the original RMarkdown, in Quarto, the number of pages are too distant from the bottom. Is there some manner to make them go a little bit down? My first lines are something like this

```
title: "Análise"
lang: pt
author: "Gabriel"
format: pdf
editor: visual
```

I tried implementing some options in pdf, like toc, but it didn't seem to work. `toc: true toc-depth: 3 lof: true lot: true`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epsHU.png)

Comment: this is going to depend on the default LaTeX templates used by Quarto and rmarkdown, as both systems currently use a pandoc/LaTeX pipeline for conversion to PDF